# Why apple splits up struct def and typedef?

Tags: c

I've been looking into the [APFS specs](https://developer.apple.com/support/downloads/Apple-File-System-Reference.pdf), if you go the General-Purpose Types section (page 9), you can see that apple gives structs (like prange_t) as bellow:

```
struct prange {
    paddr_t pr_start_paddr;
    uint64_t pr_block_count;
};
typedef struct prange prange_t;
```

But why does apple split up the typedef and struct def? Does this give a better readability or somthing else?

Comment: Probably to be concise, I think. Like `typedef struct .. {} ...;` is a bit convoluted. Maybe they wanted to be clear "this is the struct' and "this is the type for this struct" - I'm speculating.

Comment: You asked, "Why does Apple split up the typedef and struct def?"  But why did you not ask, "Why does Apple split the typedef and struct def up?"  There's no difference in meaning, just a difference in style, and perhaps readability.

Comment: The split looks  [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#WET).  `typedef struct prange { paddr_t pr_start_paddr; uint64_t pr_block_count; } prange_t;` is DRY.